# Getting Refused to load Scripts Error while running custom visual in PowerBI service in chrome

Tags: powerbi, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I am loading a external script in power bi custom visual.

powerbi-visuals-tools version - 4.2.1
powerbi-visuals-api version "5.1.0",
Getting following error while running custom visual in developer mode in chrome:

Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https://app.powerbi.com data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

The js file and CSS file which is mentioned in URL should be loaded. But giving Refused to load script error in console while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CORS restriction specific to a web link.
Can you provide the web link (URL) reference that is causing the error ?

If it's integrating forge-viewer, then please refer to this guide for how it can be done: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/embed-forge-viewer-inside-power-bi-report